# Hello World application Blackberry10 native sdk with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am just beginning Blackberry10 development. So I would like to know if there is any way to start working on the Blackberry10 native SDK with Phonegap (say 2.5) starting from a kind of "Hello World" application.

I have read the Phonegap documentation but the necessary steps are not clear.

The following are configured:

- Blackberry10 dev alpha simulator
- QNX Momentics IDE for BlackBerry 10 Native SDK (Version- 10.0.9)

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, I'm just starting as well, but according to this page (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html) it is my understanding that you don't need the momentics IDE for developing HTML5 apps using phonegap.

You can copy the cordova/phonegap sample project, and compile it by executing the command:

`ant qnx build`

(of course after adjusting `qnx.bbwp.dir` in `project.properties`)

You also need to adjust the project.properties file to set the simulator ip adress & password. You can then execute:

`ant qnx load-simulator`

to install the app in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks..I will try this out. But i would like to know the way where I can develop application using IDE (say QNX) so that code for blaclberry10 native, phonegap plugin and html5 javascript will be in one environment and easy to deploy on simulator or directly on phone.